# Get value in PHP from JSON

Tags: php, json

I need to get the objects information for `"label"`, `"name"` where `value=true` in a PHP variable and not were `value=false`.

How is this done with this `JSON` array?

If I make a var_dump of the `JSON` I get this:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#8 (3) {
    ["label"]=>
    string(4) "Name"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "txtName"
    ["value"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#9 (3) {
    ["label"]=>
    string(6) "E-mail"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "txtEmail"
    ["value"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
   [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#10 (3) {
    ["label"]=>
    string(12) "Phone Number"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "txtPhone"
    ["value"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#11 (3) {
    ["label"]=>
    string(19) "Mobile Phone Number"
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "txtMobilePhone"
    ["value"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`?

Comment: *"How is this done with this JSON array?"* There's no JSON here, that looks like the result of dumping out a PHP object graph. Could you edit your question to make it more clear what data you're actually dealing with? And add details of what you've tried, etc.

Comment: I think he's asking if this can be done with a simple json_encode([...], function($el) { return $el.value }) and the answer is NO.

Answer (score 5):

```
$arr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($json as $key => $items) {
    if($items->value == true) {
       $arr[$i]['label'] = $items->label;
       $arr[$i]['name'] = $items->name;
       $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can decode it as an object or an array, in this example I use an array.

First you want to take the JSON encoded information and decode it into a PHP array, you can use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for this:

```
 $data = json_decode($thejson,true); 

 //the Boolean argument is to have the function return an array rather than an object
```

Then you can loop through it as you would a normal array, and build a new array containing only elements where 'value' matches your needs:

```
 foreach($data as $item) {

    if($item['value'] == true) {
        $result[] = $item;
    }     

 }
```

You then have the array

```
 $result
```

at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

Simplification of the suggestions proposed by users JohnnyFaldo and som:

```
$data = json_decode($thejson, true);
$result = array_filter($data, function($row) {
   return $row['value'] == true;
});
```